# .NET Generic Redirect from Folder

Tags: .net, redirect, iis-7, directory, response.redirect

I have a folder containing multiple ASPX files as such

```
folder/file1.aspx
folder/file2.aspx
folder/file3.aspx
etc..
```

I need to move these files to another folder and change their extension to static html files as follows.

```
folder2/file1.htm
folder2/file2.htm
folder2/file3.htm
etc..
```

I'm trying to gracefully redirect the user and I'm unsure how to proceed? In .NET is it possible to intercept the request for the aspx file and redirect to the html equivalent in the new directory?

This also needs to be done programatically, I can't leave all the aspx files in the first folder with 301 redirects in the page_load. How can I grab the call to **folder/any_resource**, get the name of the resource, replace the .aspx for .htm and redirect to the new directory with the amended resource name?

Is this at all possible?

I am using the .NET framework version 4 on IIS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into URL Rewrite functionality. IIS7 supports it. It can be done through web.config file or you can use the IIS GUI to create the rules as well.

Pretty much what it does is, if you try to access folder/page.aspx server will automatically fetch folder2/page.aspx.

You can either supply an exact match for each page (tedious) or you can use a regular expression and get it done with one rule (provided all pages have same names in the next folder.)

What you want to do is catch anything going to folder/.aspx and make the server return folder2/.aspx.

So your regular expression for catching requests to folder//aspx might look like this:

```
folder/(\w*).aspx
```

Brackets around \w* will make it available for back referencing ( {R:1} )

```
folder2/{R:1}.htm
```

The above is your Redirect URL. What it does is it takes the file name and looks for .htm version of it in folder2.

If you want to redirect everything simply take away .aspx and .htm. So:

```
folder/(\w*)
```

and

```
folder2/{R:1}
```

Here is a quick tutorial that shows you where to do it in IIS. Make sure to select Redirect instead of Rewrite under Action type when creating the Rule.

[URL Rewrite](http://www.msguy.net/post/2012/02/01/url-rewrite.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll give that a go! Appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem! Hope it works fine! If you run across any problems, give a shout!

Comment: Looking into this further, and I may be wrong, but it seems that URL Rewrite will still show the requested URI in the address bar but will pull in the content from the page in the matching regex? E.g. if folder/file1.aspx is called it will retain this address in the address bar but will render the content for folder2/file1.htm. If this is the case the relative links within the page will not work correctly. I was hoping it would do a straight response.redirect.

Comment: I just had another idea...Maybe I could modify the custom error handler in the web.config. So on detection of a HTTP 404 I read the requested uri. If it was made to folder/[any file].aspx I could do a straight response.redirect to the corresponding htm page in folder2.

Comment: I think your answer is still a an excellent solution that will work in the majority of cases. Just I have a few a quirks thrown in that force me to use a different approach.